Pantallas pequeñas: no se muestra contenido completo de la página
Tengo un problema que nunca antes vi.
En pantallas pequeñas: estoy testeando una página usando F12 (en Chrome y Microsoft Edge) y resulta que está todo casi bien, el único problema es que llego a un punto  (haciendo scroll) donde el contenido de la página no se muestra, es como si se trabara la página ahi y no puedo ni hacer scroll. Aclaración. Esto solo ocurre cuando el zoom de F12 está al 100%.
Dejo esta parte del css aunque ya probé modificando las unidades del height:


html,
body {
  height: 100% !important;

  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: #242424;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  place-items: center;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
<h1>¡Hola mundo!</h1>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p>stackoverflow en español</p>
<p><b>última</b> línea</p>



espero puedan ayudar y Feliz Navidad!! :D

Lo siento, no se puede reproducir el problema. Agrega el HTML que tienes o crea un [mre] para poder ver el problema.

Igual es raro que tengas un height 100% !important y otro de100vh. Ambos chocan acá.
